# Getting strings and ints from strtok in C

Tags: c

I am trying to get user input which can sometimes be "string string" and other times be "string int". But I am getting an error for argument 3 of `sscanf(input,"%d",moves);` which states:

> "warning: format ' ' expects argument of type ' ', but argument 3 has type ' '.

I am new to C and finding the debugging rather difficult. So any help here is much appreciated!

```
char *choice = validateStr();
char *tok = strtok(choice," \n");
char *input = strtok(NULL," \n");
int moves = 0;

 else if(strcmp(choice, "forward") == 0){
        sscanf(input,"%d",moves);
        printf("%d",moves);
        forward(list,moves);
```

Comment: Using the  complete, exact warning makes for a better post.  Suggest you edit.

Comment: Sadly that was the complete warning. Solved though thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sscanf(input,"%d",moves);
```

should be changed to

```
sscanf(input,"%d",&moves);
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I made that mistake! Thank you!